# PHP Preg match numbers with a letter combination after it?

Tags: php, preg-replace, combinations

Hey I'm filtering a string and want it to go from:

```
512MBGDDR5videogeheugen
```

To:

```
512MB
```

So I tried php preg replace and did this:

```
$filterString = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+(KB|MB|GB)/", "", $string);
```

Does anyone know a way to solve this?
THANKS FOR THE RESPONSE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of replacing you can get your match like this.

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]+(KB|MB|GB))/", $string, $results);
$filterString = $results[0];
```

Comment: The expression also be simplified to `/^([0-9]+[KMG]B)/`

Comment: @Sammitch Can be, but it gives you near to nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com) that has [automatic delimiters](https://t-regx.com/docs/delimiters):

```
pattern('^[0-9]+(KB|MB|GB)')->match($string)->all();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm actually not home so I tried a javascript regex, but I think it should work:

```
$filtered = preg_replace('^([0-9]+(KB|MB|GB))(.+)$','$1',$string)
```